# MySQL queried binary data is falsey when using shorthand

Tags: mysql

I am querying a table that uses a `Binary(20)` column to store primary key (UUID) values. Why is it that Binary data is considered falsey when using shorthand in the WHERE clause like so?

```sql
# This returns 0 records:
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  my_table 
WHERE 
  primary_uuid
```

and is not considered falsey when explicitly stating `WHERE` constraints:

```sql
# This query returns all rows in the table
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  my_table 
WHERE 
  primary_uuid IS NOT NULL
  /* OR !primary_uuid */
```

#### Update (as per comment suggestion)

`EXPLAIN` will return the same result for both queries:

```
id: 1   
select_type: SIMPLE
table: my_table
type: ALL   
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 1035
Extra: Using where
```

And there are no warnings.

#### Update #2

If you would like to test this, view the [this db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tyByKS5UZ7ft6HDLXVuT14/0).

Thanks for your help,

Comment: run a `EXPLAIN query; SHOW WARNINGS;` and post those results as `WHERE 
  primary_uuid` is missing a filtering value.. Besides that also `CREATE SHOW CREATE table_name` to also post the table structure and see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) to provide example data and  a expected results based on that..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Hi, I have updated my question to supply the results of `EXPAIN`. This is not a bug that I am trying to fix, rather an investigation into why `Binary` columns are perceived as falsely when selecting truth-ey values by the shorthand in the `WHERE` clause.  As for the table structure you could just assume that there exists only a single column, `primary_uuid`.

Comment: *"This is not a bug that I am trying to fix, rather an investigation into why Binary columns are perceived as falsely when selecting truth-ey values by the shorthand in the WHERE clause"* Without table structures and example data and expected results which i have requested also i have also no idea, the best i did already by guessing ...As `SELECT` in the SQL language is declarative where you define **"what you want to have"** and not *"how to get it"** where is the `CREATE TABLE .. ` and SQL engine is meant for in short..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, updated to include a fiddle.

Comment: Consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tyByKS5UZ7ft6HDLXVuT14/1) , which feels like is more or less happening under the hood in MySQL..  In general sense do not use halfbaked filter predictes like  `WHERE primary_uuid` or `WHERE !primary_uuid` for that matter as the MySQL engine needs to do some wierd [auto type casting predicte](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) checking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-varbinary.html

> This means they have the binary character set and collation, and ***comparison and sorting are based on the numeric values of the bytes in the values***.

All of your binary fields cast to 0.

```
select cast(primary_uuid as decimal) from my_table;
```

If you insert, for example, `'1001'` that will cast as `1001` and is true. But `unhex('1001')` is `0` and false.

Based on that behavior, "numeric values of the bytes" must mean when the bytes are interpreted as characters. This makes "sense" (or at least it's consistent) when you realize [MySQL considers `binary` to be a string type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-types.html).

All of your data starts with `0D` which is character carriage return which MySQL interprets as `0`. `UNHEX('31323334')` is `"1234"` and casts to 1234.

You can convert `primary_uuid` to integers by converting it back into a hex string and then converting from base 16 to base 10.

```
conv(hex(primary_uuid), 16, 10)
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle it. Seems clunky. MySQL 8 introduces [`uuid_to_bin`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-to-bin) and `bin_to_uuid` to help working with UUIDs.

Comment: Very well put, this makes a lot more sense now. Thank you,